# How do I transfer text between different functions in C?

Tags: c, function, call

I have two .c files that I would like to compile into on executable. Having just started learning C, I'm finding it tricky to know how to transfer text as an argument between functions (which I've found to be incredibly simple in every other language).

Here are the two files:

### Program.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){

char temp[40] = stringCall();
printf("%s",temp);

}
```

### StringReturn.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char[] stringCall(){

char toReturn[40] = "Hello, Stack Overflow!";
return toReturn;

}
```

I usually get a problem that says something like "Segmentation Failed (core dumped)" or alike. I've done a lot of Googling and amazing I can't really find a solution, and certainly no simple tutorial "This is how to move text between functions".

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Did you try searching for ["string"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_string_handling) instead of "text"?

Comment: Also, this stuff is so basic that it must have taken part of the tutorial OP used to learn C...

Comment: Furthermore, this is **not related to compiler errors**. This is a runtime error. Retagged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
char toReturn[40] = "Hello, Stack Overflow!";
return toReturn;
```

This is invalid, you're returning an auto array which gets out of scope after the function returns - this invokes undefined behavior. Try returning the string literal itself (it's valid throughout the program):

```
return "Hello, Stack Overflow!";
```

Or a dynamic duplicate of your array:

```
char toReturn[40] = "Hello, Stack Overflow!";
return strdup(toReturn);
```

In this latter case, you'll need to `free()` the string in the caller function.

Comment: perhaps it is better to suggest re-write function to stringCall(char *) as third option ?

Comment: @Sergey not necessarily better, but that's also one of the options, and is a widely used pattern throughout the C standard library.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, this isn't simple in C because C can't treat strings as values.

The most flexible way to do it is this:

```
// Program.c
char temp[40];
if (stringCall(temp, sizeof temp) <= sizeof temp) {
    puts(temp);
} else {
    // error-handling
    puts("My buffer wasn't big enough");
}

// StringReturn.c
int stringCall(char *buf, int size) {
    const char toReturn[] = "Hello, Stack Overflow!";
    if (sizeof toReturn <= size) {
        strcpy(buf, toReturn);
    }
    return sizeof toReturn;
}
```

- `stringCall` doesn't return the string data, it writes it to a buffer supplied by the caller
- A buffer always comes with a size. You could use `size_t` or `ssize_t` for this rather than `int`.
- `stringCall` checks the size before writing. There are other ways to do this in a single call, all of which are either not in C89 and C99, or are defective in some other way. C11 introduces `strcpy_s`. Use what tools you can, which should be logically equivalent to checking it yourself as in my code above. Never forget to make sure there's space for the nul terminator, which invisibly lurks at the end of every C string.
- `stringCall` returns the number of bytes that it *wants* to write, even if it doesn't write anything. This means that a caller whose buffer is too small can allocate a bigger one and try again. For that matter a caller can do `stringCall(NULL, 0)` to get the size without trying any particular buffer.
- I'm using `sizeof` here because I'm using arrays whose size is known by the compiler, but in practice `stringCall` might use `strlen` or some other way of knowing how much data it wants to write.
- As I've written it, callers are required not to pass in a negative value for `size`. That's usually OK, because their buffer in point of fact cannot have a negative size, so their code is already buggy if they do. But if you want to be really sure, or if you want to help your callers catch those bugs, you could write `if ((int) sizeof toReturn < size)` or `if (size > 0 && sizeof toReturn < size)`.

"Most flexible" isn't always best, but this is good when the function is actually generating the text on the fly, especially when there isn't an easy way for the caller to know the length in advance without doing half the work that `stringCall` is supposed to do for them. The interface is similar to the C99 standard function `snprintf`.